# Naming convention for method names in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, naming-conventions

I have a class name 'Login' which is subclass of UIViewController. I was starting  to write methods for User Login and Signup . So how should i be naming the methods as  `-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender;` and `-(IBAction)signUpUser:(id)sender;` or just `-(IBAction)login:(id)sender;` and `-(IBAction)signUp:(id)sender;` . If we go by apple coding conventions which one is recommended.

Comment: Follow the camel casing and name those methods which you feel comfortable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)signUpUser:(id)sender;
```

Above two should be used because they are clearly explaining what is the action and make more sense.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) is the link explaining Cocoa Coding Conventions.

Answer (score 0):

For objective-c the methods should be detailed as possible (even if it makes their name very long).
For your case you probably should use

```
-(IBAction)signUpUser:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender
```

Edit: 
you can read this for a lot of objective-c conventions:
https://github.com/raywenderlich/objective-c-style-guide#naming